# Change axios BaseURL dynamically based on select html element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I have a vuejs app that talks to multiple identical backends that are geographically separate. Each endpoint has a unique URL - example:

```
export const SERVICE_BASE_API_URLS =  [
    { name: 'Site A', endpoint: 'http://api.a.service.com/api/v1/' },
    { name: 'Site B: 'http://api.b.service.com/api/v1' },
}
```

I am allowing users to select the endpoint they'd like to interact with via a select box. I'd like to set up the selected URL to be used in any further interactions globally for axios. I thought setting up Vue.Prototype.$current_endpoint would work.

So I have the onchange action of the select element store it's endpoint value in Vue.Prototype.$current_endpoint.

I have to setup an axios instance that is used by multiple endpoint classes once e.g. auth-header.js is imported by authenticate.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as URLConstants from '../configs/urls';

export const axios_instance = axios.create({
  //baseURL: URLConstants.Service_BASE_API_URL, // this was earlier set in .env. But this would be statically set for the vue instance
  baseURL: Vue.prototype.current_api_endpoint
})

axios_instance.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).access_token) {

      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).access_token
      config.headers["JWTAuthorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

So later on in interact-with-service.js I have

```
import {
  axios_instance
} from './auth-header';
import APIMixin from './mixin';


class ExpenseService extends APIMixin {
  get(params) {
  ...
  ...
    return axios_instance
      .get("expense" + params)
      .then(this.handleResponse);
}
```

However, I'm finding it practically impossible to set up the axios base url properly. Can someone please show me the way? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change default base url https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults

```
axios_instance.defaults.baseURL = "selected url";
```